# Writing $(m+2)^n-(m-2)^n$ in summation notation.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-theorem

I have expanded $(m+2)^n-(m-2)^n$ the following way:

$$(m+2)^n-(m-2)^n = 2 {n \choose 1}m^{n-1}+ \dots + {n \choose n-1}m2^{n-1}-{n \choose n-1}m(-2)^{n-1}+{n \choose n}2^n - {n \choose n}(-2)^n$$

Is my expansion correct and is it possible to write it in compact summation notation?

Comment: When you say "in summation notation" I am 98.3% certain that it means something involving the symbol $\sum$.

Comment: Thank you. That is correct. It's something I stumbled upon reading a paper and I was double checking the expansion and writing it neater.

Comment: Well, I think that you would have an easier time if you never leave $\sum$ land. Write each of $(m+2)^n$ and $(m-2)^n$ using that summation notation, then combine the two.

Comment: Thank you. Was confused because a lot of terms cancelled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have

$$(m+2)^n-(m-2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^km^{n-k}-\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}2^km^{n-k}=$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n(1-(-1)^k)\binom{n}{k}2^km^{n-k}=\sum_{\substack{k=0\\k\, odd}}^n \binom{n}{k}2^{k+1}m^{n-k}$$

Comment: What happens to the binomial coefficients in front?

Comment: @Maximus I've added something more, it is equal to 0 for k even and 2 for k odd.

Comment: This is missing binomial coefficients.

Comment: This is wrong, the binomial coefficients are missing. Check the binomial theorem again.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Opsss yes of course! Thanks I fix!

Comment: @A.Pongrácz Yes of course! I was so focused on the others terms and I missed it in my mind! Thanks

Comment: Yes, it happens.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following two versions of the Binomial theorem:
$$(x-y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k$$
$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k$$

Answer (score 4):

Using Newton's binomial theorem

$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom nk\, x^{n-k}\,y^k$$

we get that

\begin{align}
(m+2)^n - (m-2)^n 
&=
\sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom nk\, m^{n-k}\,2^k
-
\sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom nk\, m^{n-k}\,{(-2)}^k
\\&=
\sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom nk\, m^{n-k}\,\underbrace{\left(2^k-{(-2)}^k\right)}_{(*)}.
\end{align}

When $k$ is even, we have $(*) = 0$.
It follows that

$$
(m+2)^n - (m-2)^n 
=
\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\,\binom n{2j-1}\, m^{n-(2j-1)}\,4^j.
$$